# Best patterns and technologies to use with WCF webservice database

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, design-patterns

I am starting a new mobile application, and I want to setup webservices and a server database to use.

I decided to go with .net WCF web service and an SQL database,because I have experience with it. 
I will also use entity framework 5.

The project will have a big database and some tables might have millions of rows.

My question is, what are the best technologies or patterns that I should use? I did some researches but I couldn't find a clear answer about what is the best thing to go with.

Things like should I use repository pattern with unit of work? codefirst or database first?

I am not sure of all the things available, but a simple answer would be enough to get me started, I will do the rest of the researches (ex: use this and this and this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF had support for REST services with JSON, that are optimal approach for building web services for mobile apps.

However, Microsoft has decided to separate WCF REST from the rest of WCF, so it's now called Web API.

My suggestion to you is to learn Web API and go with it. You will loose support for "Add service reference" but then again if you're building mobile app that is not based on Microsoft technologies, that will not do much good anyway.

As for repository pattern => Entity Framework's DbContext is Unit of Work itself (hover the mouse over it and read what it says). Whether you'll use Code First or Database First is more matter of preference rather than optimization really. Both should work for you.

Since you'll have millions of rows, I'd strongly suggest that you consider some caching strategy. If your rows will not be changed that often, you might use standard caching approaches. Otherwise, if your rows change frequently, you might go with some proxy caching service that would be updated at the same time as the database but would provide results much faster when queried by storing the data in memory. You can go with your own i.e. WCF based cache that will communicate with your Web API over named pipes, or take already built solutions such as MemCached or Redis.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitly use the Repository and UOW patterns and start with a code first approach using EF. There are many books on this and domain driven design. Also if it will be a big database, you will for sure not rely only on entity framework as it is but use customizations because of performance issues that might appear.
If it is not a native mobile application but a web one REST is the way to go. Check also for Mobile Rest services.
Also depending on your business think on a cloud ready application (take Windows Azure in consideration).